# comparing strings and replacing words

Tags: python

list A, represents the text that will be replaced with the links and labels of list B

the idea is to compare the text of the `list A` with the tag of the `list B`, now ok. Here the inconvenience arises the condition only says whether or not there is the `text [0]` in `list B`, now as a replacement for that word (words, because the text [0]" The client's clock works fine. " have the word "watch, customer") so each word represents a different link

```py
listA = ['Text with label A', 'Label B with text', 'Text without label', 'Only text']
listB = [('urlA', 'label A'), ('urlB', 'label B'), ('urlC', 'label C')]

for uri, label in listB:
    print(uri, label)
    
if any('label A' in label for uri, label in listB):
    print("contains something")
else:
    print("nothing")
```

conditional is same (in theory noo?), i don't know why not find something

```py
for datail in listA:
    print(datail)
    if any(datail in label for url, label in listB):
        # condition is bad
        print("contains something")
        # how to replace that word with the tag and its url
        detalle = detalle.replace('', '')
    else:
        print("nothing")
```

To summarize I am trying to perform semantic annotation, suddenly some library or something more efficient

Comment: Can you provide a sample output you expect to see from this code. It will help refine the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do, whether it is using regular expressions if the phrases may be part of a list of values or if you are trying to find a good way to iterate over your options and see if the word exists in the look up set.

For the first option check out the library re, which helps do regular expressions and do something like

```
re.search(my_pattern, string_to_check)
```

For the second case I would recommend a dictionary, since you can easily look if a value exists in the keys of a dictionary and then get the corresponding output.

```
my_lookup_table = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
test_values = ["a", "a", "d", "c"]

for value in test_values:
    if value in my_lookup_table.keys():
        print(my_lookup_table[value])
# prints 1, 1, 3
```

Comment: this is closer to what i am looking for, but it is **not a dictionary**, it is a list where each element in turn is a list

Comment: Ah I see, so you have a list of lists that you want to search through? The example seems to be a list of tuples, so it seemed like you wanted to have a key-label relationship. You can also use nested dictionaries, so I would probably still recommend converting your data, if it is being given upstream, or starting with a dictionary if you can since it seems to fit your problem better.

Comment: I said in part because the idea seems to be understood the idea but **each element** of list A, is a **sentence**. You understood it as a key but in reality **it is a word** of that sentence, the one that I look for in each element (label) of list B, that is, **this word** is in list B. Yes / No, if it creates a link for this word (coincidence). I hope I have expressed myself better

Answer (score 0):

Based on the your question, it looks like you want to check if any of the items in `listA` is part of `listB`.

Let's first take `listA` and convert it into a tuple to look like `listB`.

```
listA = ['abc - 123', 'def - 456', 'ghi - 789', 'abc - 456']

#this will convert listA into a tuple like listB
listX = [tuple(i.split(' - ')) for i in listA]
```

Now that both `listA` and `listB` look the same, you can compare them against each other.

The below if statement will compare each element of `listX` against `listB`. If any of them is true, then it will print `'contains something'`

```
if any(True for i, j in zip(listX, listB) if i == j):
    print("contains something")
else:
    print("nothing")
```

However, if you want to know all the items that matched between `listA` and `listB`, then you can use the below two lines

```
temp = [x for x in listX for b in listB if x == b]       
print (temp)
```

The full code is listed below:

```
listA = ['abc - 123', 'def - 456', 'ghi - 789', 'abc - 456']
listB = [('abc', '123'), ('def', '456'), ('ghi', '789')]

#convert listA into a tuple to compare with listB
listX = [tuple(i.split(' - ')) for i in listA]

#check if any item in listX matches with listB
if any(True for i, j in zip(listX, listB) if i == j):
    print("contains something")
else:
    print("nothing")

#for each item that matches from listA with listB, store into temp
temp = [x for x in listX for b in listB if x == b]

#temp contains all matched items betwen listA and listB
print (temp)
```

Output:

```
contains something
[('abc', '123'), ('def', '456'), ('ghi', '789')]
```

Comment: The split ('-') is `unnecessary`, it was just an example. What I am looking for is to compare each element of the `list A` with each element of the `list B` **but** not all the element I look for a **word of the element A** with the `tag` of the `list A` [(url, label), ...}

Comment: based on the changes to `listA` and `listB`, the above answer will not work. Instead you want to compare each element of `listA` and see if they are in `listB`. Would you want to know which element of `listB` each element of `listA` matched to?

Comment: No, each item in list A is a sentence. What I want is to find if a word of that sentence is equal to the label of list B. Naturally the "sentences" can have the word more than once, so when comparing with the label of list B, this it was replaced with the url that corresponds to that tag. I hope I have clarified my question better.